# bootstrap-3 align links and buttons at the bottom of a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

As can be seen in the screenshot below, the links are not aligned at the bottom of the **div**. How do I align the buttons for **edit**, **delete**, **add cart**  at the bottom of the **div**. Note I am not using a **table**.

```
.bottomaligned {position:absolute; bottom:0;  margin-bottom:7px; margin:7px;}
.fixedheight { height: 208px; position:relative; border:1px solid; margin:7px;}
```

The relevant bits from template rendering the page whose screenshot is shown below is pasted here. Note that using the css **class="bottomaligned"** is still not aligning the links. Even when I added  **width: 300px;** to the css class **.fixedheight**, they didn't still align.

```
 <div class="row">

  <% @products.each do |product| %>


 <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-6 fixedheight ">

    <div class="bottomaligned">
     <%= link_to 'edit', edit_product_path(product), class: "btn btn-danger"  %>

     <%= button_to "Delete", product, data: {confirm: 'Are u sure?'}, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>

     <%= button_to "Add to cart", order_items_path(product_id: product) %>

    </div>
    <hr>

  </div><!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

 <% end %>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

The screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved it. See the new screenshot. I did it by adding 3 different css classes: **bottomaligned**, **bottomright** and **bottomleft**, so each link now has a different css class.

```
  .bottomaligned {position:absolute; bottom:0;  margin-bottom:7px; left: 0;}
  .bottomright {position:absolute; bottom:0;  margin-bottom:7px; margin:7px; right: 0;}
  .bottomleft {position:absolute; bottom:0;  margin-bottom:7px; left: 100px;}
  .fixedheight { height: 200px;  width: 243px;  position:relative; border:1px solid;}
```

This is how the template now looks:

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-6 fixedheight ">

  <div>
    <div >
      <span class="bottomleft"><%= link_to 'edit', edit_product_path(product), class: "btn btn-danger"  %></span>

      <span class="bottomright"><%= button_to "Delete", product, data: {confirm: 'Are u sure?'}, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %></span>

      <span class="bottomaligned"> <%= button_to "Add to cart", order_items_path(product_id: product) %></span>

     </div>
    <hr>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
```

The new screenshot:

[image]