# Bootstrap bottom align button inside .form-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have markup as follows which shows 3 text inputs on a horizontal line

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 1</label>
        <input id="f1">    
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 2</label> 
        <input id="f2">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 3</label>
        <input id="f3">
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine but I want a button to the right of "Field 3" which is horizontally aligned with the bottom of the input, `#f3`.

I've looked at the following but none of these seem to work:

- https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/
- [bootstrap-3 align links and buttons at the bottom of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232453/bootstrap-3-align-links-and-buttons-at-the-bottom-of-a-div)
- [How do I align the button to the bottom of the row/column in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943457/how-do-i-align-the-button-to-the-bottom-of-the-row-column-in-bootstrap)

The markup which I've tried adds the button in a 4th `.form-group` and then I've tried various things on the links above, such as adding `.align-bottom` to the relevant div.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 1</label>
        <input id="f1">    
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 2</label> 
        <input id="f2">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Field 3</label>
        <input id="f3">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group align-bottom">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="align-bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

Surely someone wanting the button to be aligned with the bottom of the form elements - in a nice straight line - is a common scenario. So what am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this seemingly simple task?

Comment: really? I thought that was bad practice as it's basically just making a space due to a line break, as opposed to using proper CSS rules?

Comment: if youre wanting for a more cleaner look, try wrapping the form group in a `<div>` button

Comment: Can you provide working snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work. In `.form-inline`,  `form-group` classes are aligned to the middle, just simply align it to the bottom.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
label{
  display:block;
}
.form-inline .form-group {
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
</style>
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Field 1</label>
    <input id="f1">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Field 2</label>
    <input id="f2">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Field 3</label>
    <input id="f3">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group align-bottom">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="align-bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy as overriding the rule that is causing the line break, `.form-inline` behaves this way because of the following code in bootstrap:

```
.form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Trying doing it this way.

```
<div class="form-group reset-button">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="align-bottom">
</div>

.form-group.reset-button{
display:block;
}
```

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately this makes the button appear on the line *below* the 3 inputs. I'm looking to keep everything on one line, but have the button rendered in alignment with the bottom of each of the inputs on the same horizontal line.

Comment: You want it on same line but on the bottom , i am like totally confused. Try a wireframe maybe to depict what you want. Are you saying you want 3 buttons below each input.

Comment: I've accepted an answer that works. Run that link with the sample code, but make sure you run it in a new window/tab (SO shows it inside a div that's too narrow) to see the desired effect.

Comment: Oh right, but don't override default bootstrap classes like mentioned in that. Create a new class specific for your scenario.

Comment: The block of markup in `.form-inline` also has an ID which I removed to keep the post simple. I'll use the rules supplied but target them within that ID. Good point though.